# Draw text on screen C++

Tags: c++, text, draw, gdi

I want to draw text on the screen above all the windows.
I found out about HDC and start working with it. I had 2 problems: the text was flashing and there was background. I found out the function:

```
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
```

but all it done is cancel the flashing. I still got background. My final code now is:

```
    RECT rect = { 20, 20, 200, 200 };
    SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(255,0,0));
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetBkColor(hdc,RGBA(0,255,0,0));
    DrawText(hdc, L"My text",-1,&rect,DT_LEFT);
```

I put this code in while(true) statement and sleep for 1 millisec.
Before the while i got the hdc init:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
```

So at this point i got non flashing text but with background (not transparent).
The background is half transparent so i can see what below it but it doesn't update. When i put a new window below it i can see the "background" of the old one.

I tried using wndproc like in this question:
[How to draw text with transparent background using c++/WinAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479386/how-to-draw-text-with-transparent-background-using-c-winapi)
But it does nothing at all (i cant even see the text)
I tried using the textout example from msdn site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133(v=vs.85).aspx
But it does nothing too.

How can i draw text on the screen without background at all?
Thank you guys

Comment: I never used this before, but what happens if you remove the SetBkColor() function?

Comment: Use `CreateSolidBrush` and `FillRect` to clear the background. Search for "Double Buffering" to avoid the flashing.

Comment: John - It got no effect (looks the same)
Wimmel - If i will fill rect it will draw rectangle and hide the background, i dont want to hide it. Or i didnt understand you correctly

Comment: @user2462683 ah, I misunderstood that. What you want is a bit harder, but take a look at [Creating a transparent window in C++ Win32](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3970066/33499)

Comment: You have used `RGB()` with SetTextColor() but `RGBA()` with `SetBkColor()`... for clarity I would recommend sticking with one or the other (`RGB()` for preference if you aren't setting the alpha value). However I don't think that will fix your problem...

Comment: Does the text background which you see correspond to the background colour you have set (with `SetBkColor()`, i.e. green in the example you give)?

Comment: @AAT first of all: #define RGBA(r,g,b,a) ((COLORREF)((((DWORD)(BYTE)(a))<<24)|RGB(r,g,b))) so it is the same as RGB, COLORREF got alpha channel in it value and RGB doesn't give it a value. so they are the same. second, now the background is always black, i didnt touch the code, weird.

Comment: Yeah I know that using `RGBA()` this way is the same as using `RGB()`: I said use one or the other __for clarity__, it was just some additional free advice!